# WHERE in vlookup?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I'll try my best to explain this - I know exactly how to do this in SQL but not in Excel. I have two worksheets (let's call them ws1 and ws2). In WS1 we have a 'product code' column and in WS2 we have 'product code' and 'product id' columns. I want to add a new row on WS1 which looks up the 'product id' on WS2 where the 'product code' matches.

Is this possible in excel? any hints or tips are much appreciated. Please do ask if anything is unclear.

Comment: The capitalising is habit from SQL :/. Just fill a value, so take a value from ws1 column product code, find that value in ws2 product code and return the product id from ws2 in to a cell in ws1. Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=VLOOKUP(C1,'ws2'!$D$1:$E$5,2,FALSE)` may work, if the Product Code is in `C1` of ws1 and the lookup table is in `D1:E5` of ws2 (with Product Code on the left).

Comment: Seems to do the job - perfect, thank you.